# Deploying CSS/Images/MasterPage with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have a Visual Studio project that I want to use to deploy a few CSS files, images and a master page to a SharePoint 2010 site that I have (the site will be pretty basic, simple BI type site with reports and Dashboards). I want to automate this with TFS and PowerShell with WinRM. I have the WinRM all complete, as I remote to the SP server, and can execute any PowerShell from there. I am working on trying to put together the PowerShell script to deploy the wsp file out to SharePoint. I am currently doing this

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Install-SPSolution –Identity SharepointDeployer.wsp –GACDeployment
```

I do not get any errors or anything, and I see that the deployment was successful in Central Admin, but the files are not deployed when I look at SharePoint Designer. The files are all set to over-right in Visual Studio (IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" Type="GhostableInLibrary") so I am not sure what the issue is. I am not a SharePoint or PowerShell expert, so correct me if this is not the way one would do this, as I am just following what I have seen online.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating and reactivating the feature on the site?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue how to do that. Do you have a link I can look at?

Comment: `Install-SPSolution` deploys it, `Enable-SPFeature` activates a feature. `Disable-SPFeature` deactivates a feature, and `Remove-SPSolution` retracts the solution. Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906565(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Ok, how would I enable a feature after Installing the Solution? I ran Get-SPFeature and do not see my solution in the list.

Comment: run this pwoershell to activate it...Enable-SPFeature –Identity "name of feature" –url http://sp2010. after that run get-spfeature -url

Comment: I get the following error. The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the url "http://development". Development is the url of the home page of my SP site